# I can't seem to be able to link in my .js file

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm trying to implement and link up CSS as well as JS to an HTML file provided by a friend of mine for a project I'm working on.

I've linked up the CSS with no problems, but the .js file I'm trying to link just won't work. Because the script won't work, my HTML keypad doesn't work :(

Anyone notice anything I'm doing wrong?

```js
window.pass = 1234;
window.redirectURL = 'http://www.google.com';


$(document).ready(function() {
    start();
});


function start() {
    window.tries = 0;
 
    $(".key").click(function(){
        var n = $(this).html();
        $('.screen').append( n );
        window.tries++;
        updateFlasher();
        validate();
    });
}

function updateFlasher() {
    if (window.tries <=3) {
        var dis = window.tries * 55;
        $('.flasher').css({
            'left' : dis + 'px'
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.flasher').css({
            'left' : '20px',
            'display' : 'none'
        });
    }
}

function validate() {
    if (window.tries >= 4){
        checkWin();
        $('.screen').html('');
        window.tries = 0;
        $('.flasher').css({
            'display' : 'block'
        });
    }
}

function checkWin() {
    var w = $('.screen').html();
    if (w == window.pass){
        $('.success').show().delay(5000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.success').hide(); n();
        });
        var u = window.redirectURL;
        $(location).attr('href', u );
    }
    else {
        $('.error').show().delay(1000).queue(function(n) {
            $('.error').hide(); n();
        });
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*basic reset*/
/*browsers have built in values for elements so we'll reset a few things to zero, you can add to this or remove items as needed*/

div,p,body,header,footer,section,article,nav 
{ 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
} 

img 
{ 
    border: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

/* html selectors */

body 
{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}


a:link, a:visited 
{ 
    text-decoration:none;  
}

a:hover, a:active 
{ 
    text-decoration:none; 
}

/* hide elements from browser but show for doc outline */

.hidden
{
    display: none;
}

* 
{ 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body 
{
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

::selection
{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.screen{
    height: 75px;
    width: 225px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 8px solid #2b2b2b;
    background-color: #111;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: limegreen;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    letter-spacing: 26px;
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
    position: relative;
}

.flasher {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: limegreen;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 20px;
    animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s linear infinite;
}

.keypad_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 225px;
    height: 375px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.key {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 8px solid #2b2b2b;
    line-height: 58px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5), 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    color: #eee;
}

.key:hover {
    background-color: #4b4b4b;
}

.key:active {
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.2), inset 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: #aaa;
    line-height: 62px;
}

.key.last {
    position: relative;
    left: 75px;
}

.notification {
    color: limegreen;
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 225px;
    top: 15px;
    display: none;
}


@keyframes blink {
    0%{opacity: 0;}
    50%{opacity: 1;}
    100%{opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%{opacity: 0;}
    50%{opacity: 1;}
    100%{opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>

</head>



<div class="keypad_wrapper">
  <div class="screen"></div>
  <div class="flasher"></div>
  <div class="error notification">ERROR</div>
  <div class="success notification">SUCCESS</div>
  
  <div class="key">1</div>
  <div class="key">2</div>
  <div class="key">3</div>
  <div class="key">4</div>
  <div class="key">5</div>
  <div class="key">6</div>
  <div class="key">7</div>
  <div class="key">8</div>
  <div class="key">9</div>
  <div class="key last">0</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet, it works... How come it doesn't work when I preview my webpage in Chrome?

Comment: Is main.js in the same folder as the HTML file? Where in the HTML file do you link to the CSS file? Also, have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Look at the network panel... My guess is you have a 404

Answer (score 0):

Works in my browser, all I added to your code was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

But I assume from your question that you had this working already.
You could try downloading jquery to your machine locally and referencing it locally. Perhaps it gets stuck there.